# Fetch values of other columns which have max value in given column

Tags: r, max, sapply, argmax

I can find max values of `rows, disp, hp` in mtcars dataset using `sapply` function, which gives 472 335 respectively:

```
sapply(list(mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp), max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now **I want `cyl` for these values, i.e. `cyl` of cars where maximum value of `sapply(list(mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp),max,na.rm=TRUE)` is found**.

Which function should I be using? I tried unsuccessfully with `which,rownames,colnames`:

```
mtcars(which(sapply(list(mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp),max,na.rm=TRUE)))
rownames(which(sapply(list(mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp),max,na.rm=TRUE))))
mtcars$cyl(sapply(list(mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp),max,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mtcars, hp==max(hp) | disp == max(disp))$cyl
```

Comment: Hello, Is there a possible way to get the values of other columns for sapply fetched result?

Comment: Sure, just remove $cyl at the end.

Answer (score 0):

And the data.table solution is:

```
require(data.table)
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)

mtcars[hp==max(hp) | disp==max(disp)]
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.25 17.98  0  0    3    4
2: 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.60  0  1    5    8

#  if you want to get one column, e.g. 'cyl'
mtcars[hp==max(hp) | disp == max(disp), cyl]
[1] 8 8

# if you want to get several columns, do either of:
mtcars[hp==max(hp) | disp == max(disp), .(cyl,qsec)]
mtcars[hp==max(hp) | disp == max(disp), list(cyl,qsec)]
   cyl  qsec
1:   8 17.98
2:   8 14.60
```